# Dynamically changing gxt/Sencha widgets

Tags: gwt, widget, gxt, extjs

Hi everyobody
I was trying hands on **Gxt/Sencha** and bumped on this issue of adding widgets into HorizontalPanel etc to **change widgets dynamically** but not got it to worked as I assumed it is gwt in base may be applicable to it too. I tried **repaint()** and adding widgets at runtime also but had not luck there too. Kindly suggest some solution/approach or link for this problem. Thanks in advance.
regards
la_89ondevg

Answer (score 3):

The question is terribly hard to understand but here goes :

Have you tried calling the layout() method on the container after adding the widgets?
Ensure that the container does in fact have an applicable layout.
Also try the overload by passing true as a parameter to the layout() call.

Comment: Thanks G. Davids for answering and sorry for my vague english. I tried the layout() and it worked but sorry for bothering you again but what do you meant exactly by 'an applicable layout' code wise.

Comment: The applicable layout comment was aimed at the fact that often our dev's would neglect adding a flowlayout or formlayout etc to their container. Which would then give unexpected results at runtime.

If the layout() call worked for you then that is not your problem, glad you got sorted.

Comment: The question was ill asked but I understood it was the same problem for me! Thx to both.